# Delete record out of form and update the field numbers

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

In the form I am working with it has a list of steps with the step number in there. Users can move the steps around using two buttons. If the want to move a step, they click on the record selector and then press a button. If they pressed the down button, it will move the step down one and change the number to what it's supposed to be and the same goes for the record that moved up the list. However, there are times we need to delete a step. The problem with this is that it doesn't renumber the fields and needs to be done manually.

I have tried modifying the down button code and it will move the record down one, but I run into the original problem. In essence, I need it to move to the bottom of the list and renumber the rest while doing so. I have tried using the code with a Do and loop command, but it will just number the step numbers but won't move the step and addition, it will just increase the count. For example, if I were to move step 3 out 7, it would read 1,2,4,5,6,7,8. And this will continue everytime I press the button. If I select a record and press the down button repeatedly it will move the record down without a problem.

This is the code for the button down.

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If Me.frm_Steps_Listing.Form.CurrentRecord = Me.frm_Steps_Listing.Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount Then
        MsgBox "This record cannot move down anu more!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call MoveCurrentRecord(Me.frm_Steps_Listing.Form, 1, "tbl_Steps", "Step_ID", "Step")
Exit_cmdMoveUp:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Exit_cmdMoveUp

Public Sub MoveCurrentRecord(Current_Form As Form, intMove As Integer, Current_Table As String, Primary_Key As String, Sequence_Field As String)
    Dim booSomethingMoved As Boolean
    Dim lngCurrentPosition As Long
    Dim lngNewPosition As Long
    Dim rstComponents As Recordset
    Dim rstTable As Recordset
    Dim lngCurrentRecordID As Long
    Set rstComponents = Current_Form.RecordsetClone
    Set rstTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Current_Table, dbOpenDynaset)
    booSomethingMoved = False
    'If there are no records then exit
    If rstComponents.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        With rstComponents
            'Set the current record of the clone to the currently selected record
            .Bookmark = Current_Form.Bookmark
            lngCurrentRecordID = .Fields(Primary_Key)
            lngCurrentPosition = .Fields(Sequence_Field)
            If intMove = 1 Then
                .MovePrevious
                If Not .BOF Then
                    lngNewPosition = .Fields(Sequence_Field)
                    rstTable.FindFirst "[" & Primary_Key & "] = " & lngCurrentRecordID
                    rstTable.Edit
                    rstTable.Fields(Sequence_Field) = lngNewPosition
                    rstTable.Update
                    rstTable.FindFirst "[" & Primary_Key & "] = " & .Fields(Primary_Key)
                    rstTable.Edit
                    rstTable.Fields(Sequence_Field) = lngCurrentPosition
                    rstTable.Update
                    booSomethingMoved = True
                End If
            End If
```

For the delete button the code is the same but I use this to enter.

```
Call MoveCurrentRecord(Me.frm_Steps_Listing.Form, 1, "tbl_Steps", "Step_ID", "Step")
```

The initial portion of the Public sub is the same except for when I get to the section where I'm calling.

```
If intMove = 2 Then

                   Do While Not .EOF
                    .MoveNext



                    lngNewPosition = .Fields(Sequence_Field)
                    rstTable.FindFirst "[" & Primary_Key & "] = " & lngCurrentRecordID
                    rstTable.Edit
                    rstTable.Fields(Sequence_Field) = lngNewPosition
                    rstTable.Update

                    rstTable.FindFirst "[" & Primary_Key & "] = " & .Fields(Primary_Key)
                    rstTable.Edit
                    rstTable.Fields(Sequence_Field) = lngCurrentPosition + 1
                    rstTable.Update
                    booSomethingMoved = True
                    .MoveNext


                 Exit Do
                Loop

            End If
```

I'm really not sure why the Do command doesn't work, but it will work as an If command. I appreciate any feedback on this.

After looking at the suggestion made I was able to come up with the solution.

```
If intMove = 2 Then
                    Dim i As Integer
                    i = 0
                   Do Until .EOF
                    .MoveNext
                   If Not .EOF Then

                    lngNewPosition = .Fields(Sequence_Field)
                    rstTable.FindFirst "[" & Primary_Key & "] = " & lngCurrentRecordID
                    rstTable.Edit
                    rstTable.Fields(Sequence_Field) = lngNewPosition
                    rstTable.Update

                    rstTable.FindFirst "[" & Primary_Key & "] = " & .Fields(Primary_Key)
                    rstTable.Edit
                    rstTable.Fields(Sequence_Field) = lngCurrentPosition + i
                    rstTable.Update
                    booSomethingMoved = True

                    i = i + 1
                  End If
               ' Exit Do
           Loop
            End If


            'End If
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to wade thru - can you pinpoint the code where you're trying to do your `"Do and loop command"` - Are you just tying to reset the sequence based upon the deleted record being gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used similar code, though a lot simpler as it just loops the recordset.

The field in question was called *Priority* which was edited directly to the desired value; then all other records renumber at once after the update. You should be able to modify as needed:

```
Private Sub Priority_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rst             As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngId           As Long
    Dim lngPriorityNew  As Long
    Dim lngPriorityFix  As Long

    ' Save record.
    Me.Dirty = False

    ' Prepare form.
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    Me.Repaint
    Me.Painting = False

    ' Current Id and priority.
    lngId = Me!Id.Value
    lngPriorityFix = Nz(Me!Priority.Value, 0)
    If lngPriorityFix <= 0 Then
        lngPriorityFix = 1
        Me!Priority.Value = lngPriorityFix
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

    ' Rebuild priority list.
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.MoveFirst
    While rst.EOF = False
        If rst!Id.Value <> lngId Then
            lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityNew + 1
            If lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityFix Then
                ' Move this record to next lower priority.
                lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityNew + 1
            End If
            If Nz(rst!Priority.Value, 0) = lngPriorityNew Then
                ' Priority hasn't changed for this record.
            Else
                ' Assign new priority.
                rst.Edit
                    rst!Priority.Value = lngPriorityNew
                rst.Update
            End If
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' Reorder form and relocate record.
    Me.Requery
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.FindFirst "Id = " & lngId & ""
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

    ' Present form.
    Me.Painting = True
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you provided helped give me some insight on what I needed to do. I ended up using the Do and Loop with the if statement nested inside. In addition, I needed to create a variable to increase the count.